# WCF Generated Classes

Tags: c#, wcf, partial-classes

I'm converting a sample VB Client (from a 3rd party SDK which consumes its WCF Services) to C#. The client in VB when executed, works correctly.

I'm writing a small wrapper in C# Windows Form in vs2015 to consume the same WCF Services. I was able to add the service references in VS2015.

I am having a problem making an equivalent call in VB which works but for some reason in C#, it does not work, as if the generated C# classes is incorrect.

in the working sample VB, 
I have a call ContinueGetList

```
Dim siteList() As SRAdminSys.MW_DataContractCommon
Dim iRecCount As Integer = 20
Dim Status As SRAdminSys.MW_ContinueStatusEnum                     
Status = m_wcfSysDB.ContinueGetList(iRecCount, siteList)
```

The call returns a list in siteList which is an array of SRAdminSys.MW_DataContractCommon

note: I think* the actual The array returned by the webservice , is of type MW_Site which inherits DataContractCommon - (* when I made the same call in a C# equivalent call, I get an error and when I checked the error , it mentioned that it is casting MW_Site to MW_DataContractCommon )- See further test below.

```
Partial Public Class MW_Site
        Inherits SRAdminSys.MW_DataContractCommon
```

The Reference.vb from the Generated Proxy Class:

```
Public Function ContinueGetList(ByVal iCount As Integer, ByRef list() As SRAdminSys.MW_DataContractCommon) As Integer Implements SRAdminSys.IMW_KWSAdminSysDatabase.ContinueGetList
    Return MyBase.Channel.ContinueGetList(iCount, list)
End Function
```

Now in the Non-Working prototype in C# ( it does compile though ) ,

```
int[] lst_SiteIds = new int[] { };
int iRecCount = 20;
SRAdminSys.MW_ContinueStatusEnum status;
 status = (SRAdminSys.MW_ContinueStatusEnum)adminSysClient.ContinueGetList(iRecCount,ref siteList);
```

The return value status indicated that the call failed and when I check the error - a WCF method GetLastError(), I get

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MW_DataContractCommon[]' to type 'MW_Site[]'.
```

When I check the MW_Site Partial class generated by C# Service Reference, I notice it inherits DataContractCommon, so I expected it to work:

```
public partial class MW_Site : SRAdminSys.MW_DataContractCommon {
```

Reference.cs

```
public int ContinueGetList(int iCount, ref TestUtil.SRAdminSys.MW_DataContractCommon[] list) {
    TestUtil.SRAdminSys.ContinueGetListRequest inValue = new TestUtil.SRAdminSys.ContinueGetListRequest();
    inValue.iCount = iCount;
    inValue.list = list;
    TestUtil.SRAdminSys.ContinueGetListResponse retVal = ((TestUtil.SRAdminSys.IMW_KWSAdminSysDatabase)(this)).ContinueGetList(inValue);
    list = retVal.list;
    return retVal.ContinueGetListResult;
}
        CWUtility.SRAdminSys.ContinueGetListResponse retVal = ((CWUtility.SRAdminSys.IMW_KWSAdminSysDatabase)(this)).ContinueGetList(inValue);
        list = retVal.list;
        return retVal.ContinueGetListResult;
    }
```

In relation to the partial class and inheritance of DataContractCommon - On another sample code which works in VB but not in C# when both is pointing to the same WCF service. The only difference is a VB App vs a C# App which points to their respective generated proxy classes from VS Service Reference.

```
Dim sitekey__ As New SRAdminSite.MW_Key
bRet = m_wcfSiteDB.Add(1, eKEY_COLLECTION, sitekey__)

VB, Reference.vb
Public Function Add(ByVal iSiteID As Integer, ByVal iCollectionType As Integer, ByRef iRecord As SRAdminSite.MW_DataContractCommon) As Boolean Implements SRAdminSite.IMW_KWSAdminSiteDatabase.Add
    Return MyBase.Channel.Add(iSiteID, iCollectionType, iRecord)
End Function


SRAdminSite.MW_Key sitekey__ = new SRAdminSite.MW_Key();
//COMPILE ERROR on sitekey__ although MW_Key is a partial class which inherits MW_DataContractCommon
bRet = adminSiteClient.Add(1, (int)SRAdminSite.MW_SiteCollectionTypesEnum.eKEY_COLLECTION, ref sitekey__);


C#, Reference.cs
public bool Add(int iSiteID, int iCollectionType, ref SRAdminSite.MW_DataContractCommon iRecord)
{
    SRAdminSite.AddRequest inValue = new SRAdminSite.AddRequest();
    inValue.iSiteID = iSiteID;
    inValue.iCollectionType = iCollectionType;
    inValue.iRecord = iRecord;
    SRAdminSite.AddResponse retVal = ((SRAdminSite.IMW_KWSAdminSiteDatabase)(this)).Add(inValue);
    iRecord = retVal.iRecord;
    return retVal.AddResult;
}
```

So both these examples seems to be related to the way the proxy classes the WCF Service was generated and inheriting other classes but unable to work. In the 2nd sample the error was at compile time...

Can anyone shed some light, why in VB the default generated class works when called, but in c#, the same equivalent call to the same method does not work?
I've consumed other 3rd party WCF services and normally, importing the Service Reference and consuming the methods were a breeze...

For some reason, this one, I cant wrap my head around why it will not work. Is there something I'm missing or need to modify in the way the Reference.cs is generated before I consume them?